# Vue.js updating data from created functions in a component

Tags: javascript, object, vuejs2, this

I cant update the data properties from created() functions. I tried using 'this' too but i just seem out of scope. Any help? 
Anyways a sibling component is emitting info on click, which this component should recieve and display as data, very simple, but i when i try to update the main properties of data, they just always stay the same. Im new to vue2 so any help would be appreciated.

```
const singleAc = Vue.component('singleAc', {
template: `<div class="helper_text">
            <div>  Aircraft with ID : {{ $route.params.aircraftId }} </div>
            <div><img class="airline_logo" src="//logo.clearbit.com/Ryanair.com"></div>
            <div>  Model : {{modelName}} </div>
            <div v-if="fromAp">  From: {{fromAp}} </div>
            <div v-if="toAp">  To: {{toAp}} </div>
         </div>`,
data: function() {
    return {
        company: null,
        modelName: null,
        fromAp: null,
        toAp: null

    }
},
created() {
    bus.$on('op', function(op) {
        singleAc.company = op;
        console.log(op)
    })
    bus.$on('model', function(model) {
        singleAc.modelName = model;
        console.log(model)
    })
    bus.$on('from', function(from) {
        singleAc.fromAp = from;
        console.log(from)
    })
    bus.$on('to', function(to) {
        singleAc.toAp = to;
        console.log(to)
    })
}
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the `bus` variable? Do the `console.log`s actually output something?

Answer (score 0):

Forget about global events for now, try passing your aircraft's data with [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props)
then your component should access aircraft data by adding:

```
props: ['aircraft']
```

Don't forget to point to the aircraft data model. It should look somewhere like this:

```
`<div :aircraft="aircraft" class="helper_text">
        <div>  Aircraft with ID : {{ aircraft.id }} </div>
        <div><img class="airline_logo" src="//logo.clearbit.com/Ryanair.com"></div>
        <div>  Model : {{aircraft.modelName}} </div>
        <div v-if="fromAp">  From: {{fromAp}} </div>
        <div v-if="toAp">  To: {{toAp}} </div>
     </div>`
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

singleAc is a Vue component and not a Vue instance. That's why changing data like `singleAc.company` won't work

You still gotta use `this`

Solution 1: [use arrow functions so that `this` can be used](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)

```
const singleAc = Vue.component("singleAc", {
    created() {
        bus.$on("op", op => {
            this.company = op;
            console.log(op);
        });
    }
});
```

Solution 2: store `this` in a variable

```
const singleAc = Vue.component("singleAc", {
    created() {
        var _t = this;
        bus.$on("op", op => {
            _t.company = op;
            console.log(op);
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

binding this actually solved the problem

```
 bus.$on('to', function(to) {
     this.toAp = to;
 }.bind(this))
```